# Проблема с записью в файл символов CR и LF

Tags: c++, fstream

Я считываю побайтно в бинарном режиме файл и записываю в другой.
При записи назад в файл если в первом файле будет символ `CR` программа запишет его как `CR`.
Если там был символ `LF` программа запишет его как `CRLF` а не как просто `LF`.
Если же в файле попадется `CRLF` программа запишет его как `CRCRLF`.
`CR` это `'\r'`,`LF` это `'\n'`
Записываю в файл методом `std::fstream.write()`, считываю методом `read()` с флагами `std::ios::out | std::ios::in | std::ios::binary`.
Как можно это выключить или что я делаю не так?

```
std::vector<unsigned char> sourceData;    
unsigned char byte;
    while(sourceFile.read((char *) &byte, sizeof(byte)))
    {
        sourceData.push_back(byte);
    }
```

запись после алгоритма хаффмана

```
for(auto i : bitList)
    {
        if(i)
        {
            CurNode = CurNode->one_link;
        }
        else
        {
            CurNode = CurNode->zero_link;
        }
        if(CurNode->symbol != NULL)
        {
            fileOut.write((char*)&CurNode->symbol, sizeof(CurNode->symbol));
            CurNode = MainNode;
        }

    }
```

Comment: В приведенном коде нет записи в файл

Comment: Ну так а потоки открыты в бинарном или в текстовом режиме?

Comment: @AntonShchyrov добавил, там просто запись после алгоритма хаффмана, но данные сохранены, проблема с записью

Comment: @AnT да, в один файл забыл дописать флаг...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Файл записи был открыт в текстовом формате, а не бинарном.